# ReferenceError - Budget Allocation - AdWords

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm running a script to pause my account so it only spend X per day as I have a monthly budget of Y. But when I preview the script it's saying "ReferenceError: "BudgetStrategy" is not defined. (line 2)".

I've found the article here: https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/solutions/flexible-budgets#setup

I've changed my start date and end date. Removed campaign name since I want to do it for the entire account. So I want to spend X as a whole in a day.
So my script reads as;

```
function main() {
BudgetStrategy(calculateBudgetEvenly, 30, 300);
//  setNewBudget(calculateBudgetEvenly, 10,000, 01-06-17, 30-06-17);
}
```

When I preview it, it says "ReferenceError: "BudgetStrategy" is not defined. (line 2)" which I don't understand. Please can someone clarify?

Warm regards,
Vilac

Answer (score 0):

The script is giving you an error because you have not (as far as I can guess) defined `BudgetStrategy` anywhere. If you look in the rest of the example you linked you'll see that `testBudgetStrategy` was defined later with the lines:

```
function testBudgetStrategy(budgetFunc, totalDays, totalBudget) {
     var daysSoFar = 0;
     ...
```

Functions are pieces of code that are run when you call them with a line such as `exampleFunction(args)`. They defined with something like:

```
function exampleFunction(inputArgs) {
...
...
}
```

If you look at your code you'll see that you've defined two functions:

```
function setNewBudget(budgetFunction, campaignName, totalBudget, start, end) 
{
...

function calculateBudgetEvenly(costSoFar, totalBudget, daysSoFar, totalDays) 
{
...
```

But neither of these have the same name or number of args as your first call to `testBudgetStrategy`:

```
testBudgetStrategy(calculateBudgetEvenly, 30, 300);
```

Now, if you look at the line beneath it, you'll see a line's been "commented" out. This means there are two back-slashes in front of it, making it not run when the program is run.

```
//setNewBudget(calculateBudgetEvenly, TOTAL_BUDGET, START_DATE, END_DATE);
```

This might be the code you actually want to run, given it's been defined by your script, and has the correct number of arguments being passed in (by that I mean it has four variables (words) being passed in and the function when defined has four words in it's definition.

You might want to look at a [basic guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Basics) to programming before trying to script your Google Adwords.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for getting back to me. What do you mean by "I have not defined BudgetStrategy anywhere"? I'm new to doing java so apologies if my questions sounds really basic. Does it mean, you are "calling out something to action"?

Comment: Also I've just added the full script which appears as:

Comment: Hi Tom, please see above additional comments on this topic in my answer.

Comment: Well I've updated my answer, but I really think you need to either hire a developer or bite the bullet and learn just a basic understanding of code.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for your input. Currently been studying CodeAcademy and been able to pick up a few bits and pieces. But will have to go over it again. Will also read up on your link to build up my learning.